# Why nvprof does not have metrics on floating point division operations?

Tags: cuda, floating-point, nvprof

Using `nvprof` to measure floating point operations of my sample kernels, it seems that there is no metrics for `flop_count_dp_div`, and the actual double-precision division operations is measured in terms of add/mul/fma of double-precision and even some fma of single-precision operations.

I am wondering why is the case, and how to deduce the dynamic number of division operations of a kernel from `nvprof` report if I don't have the source code?

My simple test kernel:

```
#include <iostream>

__global__ void mul(double a, double* x, double* y) {
  y[threadIdx.x] = a * x[threadIdx.x];
}

__global__ void div(double a, double* x, double* y) {
  y[threadIdx.x] = a / x[threadIdx.x];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const int kDataLen = 4;

  double a = 2.0f;
  double host_x[kDataLen] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
  double host_y[kDataLen];

  // Copy input data to device.
  double* device_x;
  double* device_y;
  cudaMalloc(&device_x, kDataLen * sizeof(double));
  cudaMalloc(&device_y, kDataLen * sizeof(double));
  cudaMemcpy(device_x, host_x, kDataLen * sizeof(double),
             cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Launch the kernel.
  mul<<<1, kDataLen>>>(a, device_x, device_y);
  div<<<1, kDataLen>>>(a, device_x, device_y);

  // Copy output data to host.
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemcpy(host_y, device_y, kDataLen * sizeof(double),
             cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // Print the results.
  for (int i = 0; i < kDataLen; ++i) {
    std::cout << "y[" << i << "] = " << host_y[i] << "\n";
  }

  cudaDeviceReset();
  return 0;
}
```

And `nvprof` output of the two kernels:

```
nvprof --metrics flop_count_sp          \
       --metrics flop_count_sp_add      \
       --metrics flop_count_sp_mul      \
       --metrics flop_count_sp_fma      \
       --metrics flop_count_sp_special  \
       --metrics flop_count_dp          \
       --metrics flop_count_dp_add      \
       --metrics flop_count_dp_mul      \
       --metrics flop_count_dp_fma      \
       ./a.out
==14380== NVPROF is profiling process 14380, command: ./a.out
==14380== Some kernel(s) will be replayed on device 0 in order to collect all events/metrics.
Replaying kernel "mul(double, double*, double*)" (done)
Replaying kernel "div(double, double*, double*)" (done)
y[0] = 24 internal events
y[1] = 1
y[2] = 0.666667
y[3] = 0.5
==14380== Profiling application: ./a.out
==14380== Profiling result:
==14380== Metric result:
Invocations                               Metric Name                                    Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti (0)"
    Kernel: mul(double, double*, double*)
          1                             flop_count_sp           Floating Point Operations(Single Precision)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_add       Floating Point Operations(Single Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_mul        Floating Point Operation(Single Precision Mul)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_fma       Floating Point Operations(Single Precision FMA)           0           0           0
          1                     flop_count_sp_special   Floating Point Operations(Single Precision Special)           0           0           0
          1                             flop_count_dp           Floating Point Operations(Double Precision)           4           4           4
          1                         flop_count_dp_add       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_dp_mul       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision Mul)           4           4           4
          1                         flop_count_dp_fma       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision FMA)           0           0           0
    Kernel: div(double, double*, double*)
          1                             flop_count_sp           Floating Point Operations(Single Precision)           8           8           8
          1                         flop_count_sp_add       Floating Point Operations(Single Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_mul        Floating Point Operation(Single Precision Mul)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_fma       Floating Point Operations(Single Precision FMA)           4           4           4
          1                     flop_count_sp_special   Floating Point Operations(Single Precision Special)           4           4           4
          1                             flop_count_dp           Floating Point Operations(Double Precision)          44          44          44
          1                         flop_count_dp_add       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_dp_mul       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision Mul)           4           4           4
          1                         flop_count_dp_fma       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision FMA)          20          20          20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems that there is no metrics for flop_count_dp_div, t

Because there are no floating point division instructions in CUDA hardware.

> and the actual double-precision division operations is measured in terms of add/mul/fma of double-precision and even some fma of single-precision operations.

Because floating point division is implemented using a Newton Raphson iterative method using multiply-add and multiply operations. Possibly even in mixed precision (thus the single precision operations)

> how to deduce the dynamic number of division operations of a kernel from nvprof report if I don't have the source code?

You really can't.